# The type signature for `isprime' lacks an accompanying binding

Tags: function, haskell

I have this code:

```
esprimo :: Int->Bool
esPrimo x = if length (div x x) == 2 then True else False
```

But I pulled the error is above

Comment: isPrime x =  all (/=0) $ zipWith mod (repeat x) [2..x-1]

Comment: Don't edit the question to a new form, once it has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what sibi said, I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x = if length [d | d <- [1..x], x `mod` d == 0] == 2 then True else False
```

this is basically the direct translation of the mathematical concept of beeing *prime* into Haskell.

As you don't need the `if` as it checks the same `==` already returns a bit more readable might be:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x = length divisors == 2
  where divisors = [d | d <- [1..x], x `isMultipleOf` d]
        isMultipleOf m n = m `mod` n == 0
```

**Please note** that this is of course not the most performant prime-test.

Comment: `if x then True else False` == `x`.

Comment: @user2407038 and if you read the answer to end you will see this just in the middle of the text and in the last code

Answer (score 2):

The exact reason for your error is because of the different cases you have used in the type signature and the type definition:

```
esprimo :: Int -> Bool -- p should be capital here to work.
esPrimo x = if length (div x x) == 2 then True else False
```

Haskell is case sensitive, so `esprimo` and `esPrimo` are different. That being said  there is other type error in your code: the type of `div` is `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`, so it returns `a` and you are applying `length` function on it. But `length` function only accepts list i.e `[a]` and not `a` which will produce you type error.